# How to map to a Lookup<string, string> object from database results using Dapper?

Tags: .net, dapper

If I have a simple SQL query such as:

```
string sql = "SELECT [NonUniqueString] as Foo, [StringValue] as Bar  FROM Table";
```

and I want to map it to a `Lookup<string, string>` object how would I do this with Dapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ILookup<string, string> lookup = connection.Query<Table>(sql)
    .ToLookup(x => x.NonUniqueString, x => x.StringValue);
```

Comment: Just to clarify this solution requires a complex type Table in order to work, I also need to remove the aliases in the SQL query.

Comment: @JonasAxelsson: yes, dapper will automatically map the properties of this class to the columns

Answer (score 0):

This is how I currently do the query and mapping, perhaps it could be done in a easier way.

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> result = await dbConnection.QueryAsync(sql);
ILookup<string, string> xxx = result.ToLookup(k => (string)k.Foo, v => (string)v.Bar);
Lookup<string, string> yyy = (Lookup<string, string>)xxx;
```